Is the gradient of the L- Lipschitz function bounded by L?
Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L ||x - y||_2,
$$
i.e., $f$ is L-Lipschitz with respect to the euclidean norm.
Can we prove that
$$
||\nabla f(x)||_2 \leq L
$$
in this case? If not is there a counter example?
It is easy to prove $||\nabla f(x)||_2 \leq nL$ if we use the definition of the Lipschitz function, since each partial derivative is bounded by $L$.
It is also easy to prove the $L$ bound if we further assume $f$ is convex.
I want to know can we prove the result with some weaker condition.

Assume $f$ is differentiable at $x$. If $\nabla f(x)=0$ then we are done, so we may also assume that $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$. Let $$v= \frac{\nabla f(x)}{\vert \nabla f(x) \vert }.$$ Since $$ \vert f(x+tv)-f(x)\vert \leq L t $$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$ and, as $t\to 0$, $$\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x) }t\to \nabla f(x)\cdot v= \vert \nabla f(x) \vert , $$ we obtain $$\vert \nabla f(x) \vert \leq L. $$
Note, Rademacher’s theorem says that if $f$ is Lipschitz then it is differentiable almost everywhere, so the assumption that $f$ is differentiable above is not necessary if you only care about the result holding up to a set of measure zero.

$+1$. Typo: $f(x+tv)-f(x) \to \nabla f(x)\cdot v$ should read $\frac 1  t [f(x+tv)-f(x)] \to \nabla f(x)\cdot v$.

Thanks for the correction :) @geetha290krm
